# Soft questions without reputation

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I would like to ask two soft questions, but i would not like to gain reputation from this. What do you think about the following procedure: 
I write my question in advance. I post a question named [Soft question] and in the body i will write that the content is missing until a moderator makes it community wiki. Flag it as community wiki. After it is done i do what i want, and no rep will be awarded.

An other algorithm would be to edit the question 10 times in a row very fast. I read that this makes a question cw but i don't know whether it has any other non trivial consequences. What do you suggest?

[I am curious about the role of coffee/tea/other_stuff while doing mathematics, and the optimal way to introduce MO to someone (for example my advisor) who might be a valuable member of the community if i could get him interested to join. Feel free to discuss the themes of the questions too.]

Comment: The question how to introduce MO to someone is a question that seems a lot better for meta.MO (this site) than for the main site. I strongly advise you to ask this question here, and not on main. If I do not misunderstand completely what you want to ask, it is quite likely to be migrated here, regardless. And, as a bonus, if you ask it here you do not have to worry about points at all :-)

Comment: The first of those questions (about coffee/tea) does not seem like a question that belongs on MO.

Comment: Perhaps the question about tea could be asked at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/.

Comment: I'm serious about my comment above.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am curious how others prepare themselves to do mathematics. Some people drink coffee, others tea, Erdős was doing Benzedrine, etc. Since in professional sport it is crucial to prepare yourself before you do it, i would like to know how other mathematicians prepare themselves before they are doing mathematics.

Comment: It would be difficult to make your post into CW by several edits very quickly, since there is [5 minutes grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits). This means that all edits you made withing 5 minutes are counted as one edit.

Comment: Maybe the real question is "why is it so complicated to make questions CW?". It takes only 10 reputation points to make your own *answer* CW, but it's impossible to make a *question* CW unless you are a moderator (10.000 points; no separate privilege "creating CW questions" at a lower threshold even exists).

Answer (score 10):

I suggest that you don't worry about possibly getting a few points before your questions are made CW. If you really care, you can make a comment like "please wait with voting until the question is made CW", or similar. In any case however I think you shouldn't try any tricks with lots of edits or with initially putting in only dummy-/placeholder text.
Edits bump the question to the top of the active questions list, which some people find seriously annoying if it happens too often and without good reason. Also you would need
to wait for a couple of minutes between any two edits in order to generate a new revision.